# Integer to Character conversion for Rock paper scissors

Tags: c++, char, int

Hello is there a different way to convert a int back to a char see comment about half way down the code. Im thinking the use of a switch or an if statement but i cannot figure out hot to apply it. i used char RPS[] = {'?', 'R', 'P', 'S'};

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std; 
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>

    //human choice function
    int hchoice()
    {
        char entry;
        int usrchoice = 0;

        while (1)    
         {
         cout <<"Choose R for Rock P for Paper, S for Sissors or Q for quit ";
         cin >> entry;
         cin.ignore(1000, 10);
         switch (toupper(entry)){
         case 'R':
           usrchoice = 1;
           break;
         case 'P':
           usrchoice = 2;
           break; 
         case 'S': 
           usrchoice = 3;
           break; 
         case 'Q':
           usrchoice = -1; 
           break; 
         } 
         if (usrchoice != 0)break;

         cout << "Invalid Entry" <<endl;


        }
    return usrchoice;
    }
    //Computer choice function
    int compchoice()
    {
          return (1 + rand() % 3);
    }
    void printresults(int computer, int human)
    {
    //Number to char converter? Can i use a switch here?
    char RPS[] = {'?', 'R', 'P', 'S'};

     cout << "Computer:" << RPS[computer];
     cout << ", Human:" << RPS[human];
     cout << ",  ";

    if (computer == human){
      cout <<"tie";
    }
    else if ( ( human==1 && computer == 2) || (human == 2 && computer == 3) || (human == 3 && computer == 1)){
    cout << "computer wins!";
    }
    else {
    cout <<"Human Wins!";
    }
    cout << endl;


    }


    int main()
    {
     // initialize the computer's random number generator
    srand(time(0)); rand();
      // declare variables
     int human = 0, computer = 0;

      // start loop
    while (1)  
    {
        // determine computer's choice
        computer = compchoice();
        // prompt for, and read, the human's choice
        human = hchoice();
        // if human wants to quit, break out of loop
           if (human == -1) break;
        // print results
         printresults(computer, human);
        cout << endl;
      // end loop
    }//while
      // end program
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your array? That's IMHO the best way to do this.

Comment: On the other hand, your while loop could use a proper condition, instead of a manual break.

Comment: @jv42 But that while loop naturally has its exit condition in the middle. I consider that a pretty standard idiom (though I usually write it using for(;;)). Writing it without the break requires either adding a boolean flag (ugly) or duplicating code (beyond ugly)

Comment: @wolfgang I was talking about the first loop. The one on `usrchoice != 0`.

Comment: @jv42 Whether it's preferable to encode things in control flow or in variables is really a matter of style; I'd go as far as replacing each occurence of "usrchoice = something;" by "return something;". Setting a flag or a variable from several places in the middle of a loop is IMHO *less* clear and readable than breaking or returning from the middle of a loop.

Comment: @wolfgang Agreed, I would use return in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a `switch` there, or a series of `if` statements. However, what you have right now is by far the most concise and -- I would argue -- the easiest to read.

One more general thing that I would suggest is to use symbolic constants (e.g. an `enum`) instead of the hard-coded numbers `1`, `2` and `3` that you have in several places in your code.